# What code should I write to display questions and multiple choice answers sequentially?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a question bank table in a MySQL database. I want to display these questions and their multiple choice answers to the browser.  The following question must be displayed after the user selects an answer for the current question.  I want to store the user entered value in a POST variable like `$_POST['store']`.  It must catch the values the user enters each time and increment.  At the end the result must be displayed, where for each correct answer one mark must be allotted.

The database table fields are `Sno`, `Question`, `option 1`, `option 2`, `option3`
and, in another table, `Q_no`, `userentered`, `corect answer`.

What PHP code and MySQL query do I write? How can I create another dynamic table so that I can compare the user entered answer to the correct answer?

Comment: @Priya try to Write the code If any errors occurs then we people can help.

Answer (score 3):

Basic PHP steps without error handling, input validation or sanitization (see the PHP manual for that):

```
<?php
/* connect to server */
try{
  $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host={$myserver}", $myuser, $mypassword);
} catch (PDOException $ex){
    die("cannot connect to database service"); 
    error_log($ex->getMessage());
}

/* create database */
$dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {$mydb}"); 

/* select database */
$dbh->exec("USE {$mydb}"); 

/* create tables */
$sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS questions (
  Sno INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  Question TEXT, 
  option1 VARCHAR(64), 
  option2 VARCHAR(64), 
  option3 VARCHAR(64)
)";
$dbh->exec($sql);
$sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS answers (
  A_no INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  Q_no INT, 
  user VARCHAR(64), 
  answer TEXT,
  INDEX Q_ind (Q_no), 
  FOREIGN KEY (Q_no) 
    REFERENCES questions (Sno)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
)";
$dbh->exec($sql);

/* add new question from HTML form (method POST) */
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO questions (
  Question, option1, option2, option3
) 
VALUES (
  ':question', 
  ':option1', 
  ':option2', 
  ':option3'
)");
$question = process_question_input($_POST['question']);
$option1 = process_option_input($_POST['option1']);
$option2 = process_option_input($_POST['option2']);
$option3 = process_option_input($_POST['option3']);
$stmt->bindParam(':question',$question);
$stmt->bindParam(':option1',$option1);
$stmt->bindParam(':option2',$option2);
$stmt->bindParam(':option3',$option3);
$stmt->execute();

/* add new answer from HTML form (method POST) */
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO answers (Q_no,user,answer) 
VALUES (
  ':question_number', 
  ':user', 
  ':answer'
)");
$question_number = process_question_number($_POST['question_number']);
$user = process_user($_POST['user']);
$answer = process_answer($_POST['answer']);
$stmt->bindParam(':question_number',$question_number);
$stmt->bindParam(':user',$user);
$stmt->bindParam(':answer',$answer);
$stmt->execute();

/* return a table with every question and associated answers */
$sql="SELECT * FROM  questions LEFT JOIN answers ON Sno=Q_no"; 
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);

/* return records for a particular question and its answers, if any */
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM  questions LEFT JOIN answers ON Sno=Q_no WHERE question=:question");
$question=process_question_input($_POST['question']); 
$stmt->bindParam(':question',$question);
$stmt->execute();
$dbh = null;
?>
```

And for your html, something like this for question:

```
<html><head><title>My question</title></head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      Option 1: <input type="text" name="option1" /><br /> 
      Option 2: <input type="text" name="option2" /><br /> 
      Option 3: <input type="text" name="option3" /><br /> 
      Input your question:<br />
      <textarea name="question"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And like this for answer:

```
<html><head><title>My answer</title></head>
  <body>
    <?php echo $question; ?>
    <form method="post">
      <input type "hidden" value="<?php echo $question_number; ?>" />
      User:<input type="text" name="user" /><br /> 
      Input your question:<br />
      <textarea name="answer"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thats all. From here I think you can get the basic idea, start working with it and tweak it at your convenience...

**[EDIT]** I've seen an upvote on this today as it was before this edit. Looking at it 5 years later, I think I did not stress enough on my answer that **this code is in no way valid for production** without proper data validation and sanitization and proper use of PDO or a DB driver with prepared statements to avoid SQL injection and other debacles. **DO READ THE PHP MANUAL ON INPUT [VALIDATION AND SANITIZATION FILTERS](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php), AND [SQL INJECTION AVOIDANCE](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)**.

I've edited the code to make use of [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql since at this moment mysql is [way outdated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and should never be considered when writing fresh code.

Also edited the schema, setting `Q_no` as a `PRIMARY KEY` and `Sno` as a `FOREIGN KEY` referencing it, for referential integrity; and adding an extra column to the answers table, a primary key, because as a general rule you have some indexed unique id in your data records to be able to reference them quickly and properly (If you ever find a schema without it, don't be stupid and ask the dbs to add it. Do not write shitty DDL code that does not keep referential integrity or DML queries that run with absurdly poor performance because they use joins and where clauses against columns that should be indexed and have foreign constraints. And if you try to fix it with materialized views let me tell you you are going to find out what developer's hell looks like).

It's worth mentioning that storing each option in a column is usually a bad idea. Not flexible enough; It probably should be normalized by having an extra table `options` where each option would have a unique pair `optionnumber`,`Q_no` reference.

*As a side note I think I've probably spent twice the time editing this answer to match the most basic coding standards than I did when first answering it in an equally functional way. And clients still wonder why it takes an experienced developer almost as much time or even more time than a junior to get some things done... (although, to be fair, in the real world an experienced developer would probably be using some kind of ORM or a more complete data abstraction layer provided by a framework she/he has become familiar with, automating most of this stuff with annotations, configuration, implied configuration through coding conventions, etc.)*

As a bonus, some resources of interest:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Removed my downvote and and added another vote. Earlier there was just one single line of SQL query. :)

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree that was a poor one. (Trying to quickly hit the main spot while preparing a full answer). Thanks for the upvote.